# Reset a React Native Formik form from outside the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik

I know you can use `resetForm` in Formik to reset the form in `onSubmit`. However, is there a way to reset it programmatically by assigning it a ref and calling a rest form method on it somehow?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

there is a prop called innerRef to make ref for a formik form

```
<Formik
   innerRef={(p) => (this.formik = p)}
/>
```

then use it like this:

```
onPress={() => this.formik.resetForm()}
```

Or with a functional component:

```
const formikRef = useRef();
<Formik
  innerRef={formikRef}
  ...
/>
```

and then use with

```
onPress={() => formikRef.current?.resetForm()}
```

Comment: https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik Try out this if this doesn't work

Comment: TS still complains about `{}` so here is a one-liner that will make formik and yourself happy:
`const formikRef = useRef<FormikProps<Record<string, unknown>>>(null);`

Comment: @MrWashington with this I couldn't use the formikRef with innerRef

Comment: What's your proposed solution then ;-) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach using `useFormik` hook.

```
import { useFormik } from "formik";

export default function LoginScreen() {

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: ""
    },
    onSubmit: (val) => console.log(val),
  });


  return(
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={formik.handleChange("email")}
      value={formik.values.email}
      placeholder="Enter your email"
    />

    {formik.touched.email && <ErrorText>{formik.errors.email}</ErrorText>}

    <Button onPress={formik.handleSubmit}>Login</Button>

    <Button onPress={formik.resetForm}>Clear</Button>
  );
}
```